# Missing local variable in a function factory in Python

Tags: python-3.x, factory, locals

I am using `Python 3.5`. I would like to create a factory where local variables of the outer function can be overwritten by user kwargs.

When doing so, I found out that some variable are not defined in the inner scope without apparent reasons.

Here is a MWE of the function factory:

```
def TicksFormatterFactory( \
    title=None, target='xaxis', limits=100 \
   ,major_locator=None, major_format=None, major_gridstyle=None, major_rotation=90, major_fontsize=7 \
   ,minor_locator=None, minor_format=None, minor_gridstyle=None, minor_rotation=None, minor_fontsize=None \
   ,title_kw=dict() \
):
    pprint.pprint(locals())   # (1)
    varKeys = locals().keys() # (2)
    def inner(axe, **kwargs):

        pprint.pprint(locals())   # (5)

        # Allow User to overwrite settings using kwargs:
        settings = dict()
        for k in varKeys:
            settings[k] = kwargs.get(k, locals().get(k)) # (3)

        pprint.pprint(settings) # (4)

    return inner
```

A simple call to the factory and its inner function:

```
test = TicksFormatterFactory(minor_fontsize=4)
fig, axe = plt.subplots()
test(axe, title='Hello world')
```

Leads to:

```
# (1)
{'limits': 100,
 'major_fontsize': 7,
 'major_format': None,
 'major_gridstyle': None,
 'major_locator': None,
 'major_rotation': 90,
 'minor_fontsize': 4,
 'minor_format': None,
 'minor_gridstyle': None,
 'minor_locator': None,
 'minor_rotation': None,
 'target': 'xaxis',
 'title': None,
 'title_kw': {}}

# (5)
{'axe': <matplotlib.axes._subplots.AxesSubplot object at 0x0000027793B02BE0>,
 'kwargs': {'title': 'Hello world'},
 'major_fontsize': 7,
 'major_format': None,
 'major_gridstyle': None,
 'major_locator': None,
 'major_rotation': 90,
 'minor_fontsize': 4,
 'minor_format': None,
 'minor_gridstyle': None,
 'minor_locator': None,
 'minor_rotation': None,
 'target': 'xaxis',
 'varKeys': dict_keys(['major_gridstyle', 'major_format', 'minor_format', 'target', 'minor_gridstyle', 'major_fontsize', 'minor_rotation', 'minor_locator', 'major_rotation', 'major_locator', 'title_kw', 'title', 'limits', 'minor_fontsize'])}

# (4)
{'limits': None,
 'major_fontsize': 7,
 'major_format': None,
 'major_gridstyle': None,
 'major_locator': None,
 'major_rotation': 90,
 'minor_fontsize': 4,
 'minor_format': None,
 'minor_gridstyle': None,
 'minor_locator': None,
 'minor_rotation': None,
 'target': 'xaxis',
 'title': 'Hello world',
 'title_kw': None}
```

What I have seen deeper:

Variable pointed by `'limits'` key is not defined in inner scope:

```
locals()[k] # (3')
```

Fails for `'limits'` key (in fact the third factory parameter, whatever it is called is not passed to inner). This is why I have changed from `# (3')`  to `# (3)` and I must store keys from outer scope with `# (2)` in order to keep track of keys and make the MWE working.

This is totally puzzling me!

My question is: **Why some of my locals variable does not reach the inner scope of my factory?**

Comment: BTW, I guess there's a `return inner` missing from the function factory you posted.

Comment: I'm frankly surprised that `# (5)` prints anything except `axe`, `kwargs` and `varKeys` as you're not referencing any other local variable (local to the inner function, of course). Are you sure this is the code (with the `return inner` fix of course) that produces your output? If it is - you're using some very exotic Python interpreter!

Comment: btw. unrelated - I don't think `title_kw=dict()` in the outer function's definition does what you think it does - it will create a dictionary only once when evaluating the function and that dictionary will be used for all subsequent calls to that function. If you were to modify `title_kw` anywhere within the scope, it will remain modified in the next call that omits the `title_kw` argument, too. Never use mutables as function arguments unless that's precisely the behavior you seek, and it's not far more often than it is.

Comment: @zwer: thanks for pointing out that you need to reference an outer variable in order for it to appear in a nested function's locals. I updated my answer accordingly. My guess is that in `inner`'s original version the OP references all of the outer function's parameter except `limits`.

Comment: @zwer, You are right this is why I have observed, sorry if I have not made it clear.

Answer (score 1):

I tried your MWE and it gave me different results (Python 3.5.2):

```
>>> test = TicksFormatterFactory(minor_fontsize=4)
{'limits': 100,
 'major_fontsize': 7,
 'major_format': None,
 'major_gridstyle': None,
 'major_locator': None,
 'major_rotation': 90,
 'minor_fontsize': 4,
 'minor_format': None,
 'minor_gridstyle': None,
 'minor_locator': None,
 'minor_rotation': None,
 'target': 'xaxis',
 'title': None,
 'title_kw': {}}
>>> test(1, title='Hello')
{'axe': 1,
 'kwargs': {'title': 'Hello'},
 'varKeys': dict_keys(['title_kw', 'minor_fontsize', 'minor_rotation', 'minor_gridstyle', 'minor_format', 'minor_locator', 'major_fontsize', 'major_rotation', 'major_gridstyle', 'major_format', 'major_locator', 'limits', 'target', 'title'])}
{'limits': None,
 'major_fontsize': None,
 'major_format': None,
 'major_gridstyle': None,
 'major_locator': None,
 'major_rotation': None,
 'minor_fontsize': None,
 'minor_format': None,
 'minor_gridstyle': None,
 'minor_locator': None,
 'minor_rotation': None,
 'target': None,
 'title': 'Hello',
 'title_kw': None}
```

Which is what I expected. Calling `locals()` inside `inner` shouldn't return the outer function's parameters, simply because they're not local to `inner` unless you reference them.

You need to access `TicksFormatterFactory`'s locals this way:

```
def TicksFormatterFactory( \
    title=None, target='xaxis', limits=100 \
   ,major_locator=None, major_format=None, major_gridstyle=None, major_rotation=90, major_fontsize=7 \
   ,minor_locator=None, minor_format=None, minor_gridstyle=None, minor_rotation=None, minor_fontsize=None \
   ,title_kw=dict() \
):
    pprint.pprint(locals())   # (1)
    localVars = locals() # (2)
    def inner(axe, **kwargs):

        pprint.pprint(locals())   # (5)

        # Allow User to overwrite settings using kwargs:
        settings = dict()
        for k in localVars:
            settings[k] = kwargs.get(k, localVars.get(k)) # (3)

        pprint.pprint(settings) # (4)

    return inner
```

Which yields:

```
>>> test = TicksFormatterFactory(minor_fontsize=4)
{'limits': 100,
 'major_fontsize': 7,
 'major_format': None,
 'major_gridstyle': None,
 'major_locator': None,
 'major_rotation': 90,
 'minor_fontsize': 4,
 'minor_format': None,
 'minor_gridstyle': None,
 'minor_locator': None,
 'minor_rotation': None,
 'target': 'xaxis',
 'title': None,
 'title_kw': {}}
>>> test(1, title='Hello')
{'axe': 1,
 'kwargs': {'title': 'Hello'},
 'localVars': {'limits': 100,
               'major_fontsize': 7,
               'major_format': None,
               'major_gridstyle': None,
               'major_locator': None,
               'major_rotation': 90,
               'minor_fontsize': 4,
               'minor_format': None,
               'minor_gridstyle': None,
               'minor_locator': None,
               'minor_rotation': None,
               'target': 'xaxis',
               'title': None,
               'title_kw': {}}}
{'limits': 100,
 'major_fontsize': 7,
 'major_format': None,
 'major_gridstyle': None,
 'major_locator': None,
 'major_rotation': 90,
 'minor_fontsize': 4,
 'minor_format': None,
 'minor_gridstyle': None,
 'minor_locator': None,
 'minor_rotation': None,
 'target': 'xaxis',
 'title': 'Hello',
 'title_kw': {}}
```